# How to merge array with result in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code in Codeigniter, but somehow array_merge does not want to work, how is it possible to merge array to the result?

```
$categories = $this->get_categories();

    $data = array();

    foreach ($categories as $index) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('questions');
        $this->db->where('category', $index);
        $this->db->order_by('id','RANDOM');
        $this->db->limit(3);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        array_merge_recursive($data, $query->result());


    }

    return $data;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the result of `array_merge_recursive()` to the `$data` string:

```
$data = array_merge_recursive($data, $query->result());
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried but, is it a must to save into $data, can it be different variable? ex.: $res?

Comment: Yes you can, I try to take into account how readable the code is overall, i.e is `$data` the best variable name for the array of results? or would something like `$categoryQuestions` make more sense a year from now.